# cannot mount windows ntfs partition on linux

Tags: linux, partitioning, ntfs

I have a partitioned HDD with Linux and Windows on it.
I cannot access Windows anymore (system 32 etc ...) and I want to get back some data I have on it before removing it.
However I cannot access it.
I am currently on a liveUSB linux and I got the following resultfrom fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 116.5 GiB, 125069950976 bytes, 244277248 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 8436AE0E-4019-460C-849F-55F73683F0B6

Device             Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1      2048    534527    532480  260M EFI System
/dev/mmcblk0p2    534528    567295     32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/mmcblk0p3    567296 168339455 167772160   80G Microsoft basic data
/dev/mmcblk0p4 240867328 242634751   1767424  863M Windows recovery environment
/dev/mmcblk0p5 242636800 244275199   1638400  800M Windows recovery environment
/dev/mmcblk0p6 191952896 240867327  48914432 23.3G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sda: 29.8 GiB, 32008830976 bytes, 62517248 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x40993ab6

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          0 3899391 3899392  1.9G  0 Empty
/dev/sda2       3830956 3835883    4928  2.4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

My data are on /dev/mmcblk0p3 (remark : I don't know why my HDD is a mmcblk I thought it would appear as a /dev/sda or something like that).

The command mount -t ntfs /dev/mmcblk0p3 /media/tmp returns :

```
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/mmcblk0': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/mmcblk0' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# mount -t ntfs /dev/mmcblk0p3 /media/tmp/
Failed to read last sector (191385007): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/mmcblk0p3': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/mmcblk0p3' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

I tried ntfs,vfat and ntfs-3g types with the same result.
Note that I have access to the Linux 23.3G partition